# How to tag all members of an IRC channel

Tags: chat, irc, hubot

Is there a way to tag all members of an IRC channel in a message rather than mentioning each of their names in the message? Or is there another way to send a notification to all members of the channel? Maybe like an announcement protocol?

The context for this is a Hubot announcement to the channel, but with a higher priority to tag all (I know i can loop through the members of the channel and tag them in the message, but that is a pretty ugly message with 30+ channel members).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The IRC protocol ([RFC 1459](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1459)) does not include the notion of notification in `PRIVMSG` nor in `NOTICE` commands, that are the common ways to communicate directly with a user (or a list of users).

**The concept of notification is only a matter of implementation, client side**.

Most IRC clients do include a notion of `highlight`, that when the nickname of the current user is part of any message you are able to see, an alert is triggered, which makes the event more likely to attract the attention of the target, since it differenciates itself from all the other events.

This is not part of the protocol specifications and you will have to handle that manually, I guess.

Comment: That said, I really don't think you will last very long on public channels if you get to actually implement that feature. This will be considered as spam and you will end up kicked/banned from the channel (or the network).

Comment: Yea I get that, this setup is for a channel our team has at work. Just looking for a simple way to send out announcements. Unfortunately sounds like I'm going to need to tag all the members. :(